# Zend framework modules and Reflection

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection, namespaces

i'm a bit confused about modules, namespace and reflection.

```
$obj = new default_Model_foo();
$obj->bar();
```

The code above runs properly, but i need to add reflection;

I've got these variables:

```
$moduleName = "default";
$modelName  = "foo";
$function   = "bar";
```

I would like to instantiate a class at runtime, how can do it?

Thank you!
Mirco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$modelClass = "{$moduleName}_Model_{$modelName}";
$obj = new $modelClass();
$obj->$function();
```